# CSS scale an image and fill the container

Tags: jquery, html, image, css

There are 3 cases concerning image dimensions:

1. `image width > image height`
2. `image width < image height`
3. `image width == image height`

I need to use `img` to display an image which is inside a `div`.

```
<div class="container">
    ...
    <img class="scale-and-fill" src="..." />
    ...
</div>
```

How to:

1. If both dimensions of the image are smaller than the container, scale it up while maintaining its ratio and let the shorter dimension match the dimension of the container.
2. If both dimensions of the image are larger than the container, scale it down while maintaining its ratio and let the shorter dimension match the dimension of the container.
3. If one dimension of the image is larger but another one is smaller than the container, scale up the smaller dimension to match the container dimension, and crop the remaining part of the overflow image.

What should be entered in the CSS classes below?

```
.container {
   ...
}
.scale-and-fill {
   ...
}
```

---

#### Update

Include screenshot to illustrate my problem clearly.

[image: Screenshot illustrating my problem]

Comment: There no way the ratio can be maintained if you scale it beyond its original size.

Comment: I mean the width:height ratio.

Comment: only one can be maintained `height` or `width`

Comment: Is img mandator? setting div background would not be enough? in that case you can use cover - contain attribute

Comment: if you cannot use javascript at all, it looks hard. Because i don-t think in css you can check aspect ratio of img.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to apply two different class in the different situation:

```
.scale-and-fill1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.scale-and-fill2 {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

This should mantain proportion, but to pickup the correct class you should use a little bit of javascript.

i would add this jquery javascript:

```
$(document).ready(
  $('.container img').each(function() {
    var ratio = $(this).width() / $(this).height();
    if (ratio > 1) {
      $(this).attr('çlass','.scale-and-fill2');
      $(this).attr('left',$('. container').width()/2 - $(this).width() / 2);
    } else {
      $(this).attr('çlass','.scale-and-fill1');
      $(this).attr('top',$('. container').height()/2 - $(this).height() / 2);
    }
  });
)
```

Comment: Ya, the container is of fixed size, e.g. `width: 100px; height: 100px;`

Comment: you didn t mention any center aligning in your question when i answered. i updated the answer, please write it even on the question, a image as a reference may be unclear

Answer (score 0):

You best bet would be to downscale. Lets assume the height doesn't fit. If that's the case, the below will be helpful

```
.container {
   width: 250px; /* Adjust as needed */
   height: 200px; /* Must be a litle smaller than the images original height */
   overflow: hidden;
}

.scale-and-fill {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto; /* The image will now fit since 
  .container is smaller than the original size */
}
```

Check out this tutorial on image control at [webdesignsharepoint](http://webdesignsharepoint.com/control-elements-that-contain-images-with-jquery/)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width/height of .container, f.e.:

```
.container {
width: 300px;
height: 250px;
}
```

And set the style for image:

```
.scale-and-fill {
display: block;
width: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Well, what exactly do you want to get? Can you provide an example?

Comment: I will try to create some screenshots to illustrate my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with only css. The problem you describe has this form:

```
IF (image-dimensions) THEN (css-rule)
```

For this you need scripting.

Answer (score 0):

Use the aspect ratio of your choice. 16/9's for HD displays.

```
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
}

.scale-and-fill {
  width: 100%;
  height: unset;
  object-fit: cover;
}

@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  .scale-and-fill {
    width: unset;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```